# Separate bibliographies for phdthesis and mastersthesis in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I want separate bibliograhies for phdtheses and masterstheses in biblatex 3.0.

The bib-keys @phdthesis and @masterthesis will be treated just like @thesis by biblatex (with an additional bib-field "type").

Thus

```
\printbibliography[type=thesis, heading=subbibliography, title={Theses}]
```

collects all kind of theses.
And

```
\printbibliography[type=phdthesis, heading=subbibliography, prefixnumbers=P, title={Doctoral Theses}]
\printbibliography[type=mastersthesis, heading=subbibliography, prefixnumbers=M, title={Master's Theses}]
```

throws a warning

```
Package biblatex Warning: Type 'phdthesis' not found ...
```

What can I do to separate phdtheses and masterstheses automatically? Is it possible to filter by the bib-field "type" (not the bib-key)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `keywords` you can use the `type` field directly in a bibcheck. The `type` field is automatically populated with the correct string when Biber converts `@phdthesis` and `@mathesis` to `@thesis`. (The conversion happens in such a way that aside from the `type` field, there is no difference between `@phdthesis` and `@mathesis` for either Biber or `biblatex`.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[defernumbers,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\defbibcheck{phdthesis}{%
  \iffieldequalstr{type}{phdthesis}
    {}
    {\skipentry}}
\defbibcheck{mathesis}{%
  \iffieldequalstr{type}{mathesis}
    {}
    {\skipentry}}

\begin{document}
\cite{geer,loh}
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=P]
\printbibliography[check=phdthesis, heading=subbibliography, title={Doctoral Theses}]
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=M]
\printbibliography[check=mathesis, heading=subbibliography, title={Master's Theses}]
\end{document}
```

[image: split bibliography in the MWE]

Comment: Thanks! This solves my problem. For I am using biblatex 3.0 I just had to replace the newrefcontent-command by the prefixnumbers-parameter as @DavidPurton already explained.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you could do it with a source map. Copy the `thesis` type field to the `keywords` field and then filter based on that. Note that this code is for `biblatex 3.0` as you have specified. For more recent versions of `biblatex` you can't use the `prefixnumbers` option. But the source map idea is the same.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[defernumbers,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\pagestyle{empty}
% copy the thesis type field to the keywords field
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \pertype{thesis}
      \step[fieldsource=type, final]
      \step[fieldset=keywords, origfieldval]
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\cite{geer,loh}
\printbibliography[keyword=phdthesis, heading=subbibliography, prefixnumbers=P, title={Doctoral Theses}]
\printbibliography[keyword=mathesis, heading=subbibliography, prefixnumbers=M, title={Master's Theses}]
\end{document}
```

[image]

For more recent versions of `biblatex` you would print your bibliographies like this (I think):

```
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=P]
\printbibliography[keyword=phdthesis, heading=subbibliography, title={Doctoral Theses}]
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=M]
\printbibliography[keyword=mathesis, heading=subbibliography, title={Master's Theses}]
```

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer that solves my problem, too. However, I prefer using the "check" attribute (in the other solution), because setting the keywords here seems to be more work-around-ish.